# Create Massachusetts kinetic energy

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

I've been lurking around the cryptic crosswords lately, and I have to say their clues are fascinating. So without further ado, here's a selection of clues of my own design:

Henry steals cow from English university. (4)
Killed in action rising from the Orient. (3)
Louis breaks end off French rafter lease. (9)
"Listen!" said Cicero, "A gold Princess of Wales." (4)
Walter's son bought an art museum. (8)
Nikola took every single Latvian ant's head. (5)
Soichiro is dear Russian, yes. (5)
Seven sisters of Japan heard to prosecute tavern university. (6)
Spanish for scary, controlling, heedlessly executing King Ferdinand. (7)
Bavarian Motors executives: "blinkers mustn't work." (3)
Iron railroads lead Aristide to Enzo. (7)
Honest Abe talks of connecting with head of Old Leland Nelson. (7)

Extra points if you can figure out the category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers are as follows

> Ford = Oxford - Ox
>  Kia = **K**illed **i**n **a**ction
>  Chevrolet = Chevro(n) + let (lease)
>  Audi = Au (gold) + Di (Diana)
>  Chrysler = double definition
>  Tesla = **t**ook **e**very **s**ingle **L**atvian **a**nt
>  Honda = Hon (honey/dear) + Da (Russian "yes")
>  Subaru = Su(e) + bar (tavern) + U (university)
>  Porsche = Por (Spanish "for") + **s**cary **c**ontrolling **h**eedlessly **e**xecuting
>  BMW = **b**linkers **m**ustn't **w**ork
>  Ferrari = Fe + rr + ari (Aristide)
>  Lincoln = Linc (sounds like link) + **O**ld **L**eland **N**elson

and they are all

> Car Manufacturers

Title

> This is also a cryptic clue cluing **Make** = Ma + K.E. and these are all car *makes*.

Comment: Shoot, just as I was typing it up :P

Comment: Excellent, right on all counts! And how does the title fit into this?

Comment: @NoName woops, forgot about that. Edited now

Comment: No biggie - I did forget to add the length clue, after all